# Updating label of a ButtonField from PopupScreen

Tags: java, blackberry

I have a ButtonField on MainScreen, from which I am pushing a PopupScreen where I have added an ObjectListfield. What I want to do is to update the label of ButtonField on MainScreen with the element selected from ObjectListfield of PopupScreen.

Please tell me if it is possible to do without using `Dialog` class (I really want to use `PopupScreen` and not `Dialog` class) and the method by which this can be done. I'd appreciate if some sample code will be provided.

I have added my code.

```java
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm;
    ButtonField btn;
    public MyScreen() {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        super();
        setTitle("MyTitle");


        btn = new ButtonField("label",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
        final mypopup mps = new mypopup();

        btn.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context) {     
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushModalScreen(mps);      
            }
        });

        hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        hfm.add(btn);
        add(hfm);
    }

    public void setlabel(String labelnew) {
        btn.setLabel(labelnew);
    }

    public String getlabel() {
        return this.btn.getLabel();
    }
}

class mypopup extends PopupScreen implements FieldChangeListener {

    String it;

    ObjectListField obj = new ObjectListField() {
        public boolean navigationClick(int status,int time) {
            int selectedindex=obj.getSelectedIndex();
            it=(String)obj.get(obj, selectedindex);

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());

            /*MyScreen my=new MyScreen();
            my.btn.setLabel(it);
            my.invalidate(); */
            //close();

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /* This im doing to see that setlabel and getlabel are
                                working properly */     
                    MyScreen my=new MyScreen(); 
                    my.setlabel(it);                 
                    String gt=my.getlabel();     
                    Dialog.alert(gt);            
                    my.hfm.invalidate();                             

                        //the label of button is changed but not updating in mainscreen.
                            }
            });

            return true;        
        }
    };

    public mypopup() {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager());

        String[] type=new String[] {"a","b","c","d"};
        obj.set(type);
        add(obj);       
     }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: `//the label of button is changed but not updating in mainscreen.` - You are wrong actually. You are creating a new MyScreen object, and the label change is done on that screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change following block of code,

```
MyScreen my = new MyScreen();
my.setlabel(it);
String gt = my.getlabel();
Dialog.alert(gt);
my.hfm.invalidate();
```

With the code block,

```
Screen scr = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();
if (scr instanceof MyScreen) {
    MyScreen my = (MyScreen) scr;
    my.setlabel(it);
    my.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the button in one Manager either `HorizontalFieldManager or VerticalFieldManager` and after setting text on button invalidate the managerlike this way

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{

  ButtonField btn;
  public MyScreen()
 {        
// Set the displayed title of the screen       
super();
setTitle("MyTitle");


btn=new ButtonField("label",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
final mypopup mps=new mypopup();

btn.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener()
{
    public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context){

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushModalScreen(mps);

    }
});

HorizontalFieldManager hfmToholdButtons = new HorizontalFieldManager();
btn.setLabel(mps.gettext());
hfmToholdButtons.add(btn);
hfmToholdButtons.invalidate();
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a ton for replying,but this is not working. I figured out a mistake and changed it in my code. I removed btn.setLabel(mps.gettext()) because i think this was causing button label to set as null right from the start(launch of the app). I am editing my code, please take a look at it.